# How to show the list of Folders and files of My Drive folder using PHP

Tags: google-drive-api

Can anyone let me know how to access all the files and folders of My Drive from *Google Drive*.

I am using :

```
$client = new Google_Client();
// Get your credentials from the APIs Console
$client->setClientId('1095973606032-jkkjsp0ja5qdvp6f8p629964a2n0aqpn.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('1Tkpr3IVYX5n7YtwR_cI3Sui');
$client-    >setRedirectUri('http://staging.test.jbiprojects.co.uk/google_drive/drive.php');
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');

$service = new Google_DriveService($client);

$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

Am I doing something incorrect here?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Google [Drive SDK PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php). It will get you up and running if you copy-paste the code.

Instead of uploading a file, you should make a call to:

```
$service->files->list
```

Check out the PHP sample for [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) here.